Argocd Image updater: git write back method: could not read Username for 'https://github.com'
I am using argocd image updater with the git write back method to git. It is working fine with argocd method but when I change to git write back method it is having could not read Username for 'https://github.com' error. Config looks correct as well
Error:level=error msg="Could not update application spec: `git fetch origin --tags --force --prune` failed exit status 128: time=\"2024-10-10T09:38:28Z\" level=fatal msg=\"dial unix /tmp/reposerver-ask-pass.sock: connect: connection refused\"\nerror: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/local/bin/argocd-image-updater'\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled" application=dev-argo
time="2024-10-10T09:38:28Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=2 images_skipped=0 images_updated=0 errors=1"

I used below secret:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: github-creds1
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository  # Important label
stringData:
  type: git
  url: https://github.com/******.git
  username: ***
  password: ****

With annotations in the argo file as:
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-method: git:secret:argocd/github-creds1
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-repository: https://github.com/*.git
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-branch: dev

I am using  quay.io/argoprojlabs/argocd-image-updater:v0.14.0 Image
It is not even able to pick up the repo.
